# SQL GroupBY columnABC and extracting distinct columnABC values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query and its giving me desired result but i want to repeat this query to be executed for all WardNos in Voter table.

```
SELECT WardNo, (SELECT COUNT(Gender) 
                FROM dbo.Voter
                WHERE (Gender = 'Male') AND (WardNo = '105')) AS MaleVoter,
               (SELECT COUNT(Gender) AS Expr1
                FROM dbo.Voter AS Voter_2
                WHERE (Gender = 'Female') AND (WardNo = '105')) AS Female-voter
FROM dbo.Voter AS Voter_1
WHERE (WardNo = '105')
GROUP BY WardNo
```

and output should be like this

```
WardNo Cast Male Female
103    abc  55   25
104    abc  192  45
```

Comment: What database? SQL Server, Oracle? And please post the structure of your table.

Comment: I am using SQL Server with VarChar() dataTypes

Comment: Um, where is `Cast` coming from?  It's not in your select list...

Comment: @Hamad, was my answer not correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace '105' with Voter_1.WardNo, which gives you a reference to the outher table Voter_1 in the inner queries,

and remove

```
WHERE     (WardNo = '105')
```

and that should give you the result for all WardNo's

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have only two columns in your table `Ward` and `Gender`. Below is a query that will get you counts of voters by `Gender` grouped by `Ward`.

```
declare @Voter as table
(
Ward int,
Gender varchar(max)
)

Insert into @Voter values(106, 'Male')
Insert into @Voter values(106, 'Male')
Insert into @Voter values(107, 'Male')
Insert into @Voter values(107, 'Female')

Select * from @Voter

Select Ward, 
sum(case when Gender = 'Male' then 1 else 0 end) AS male,
sum(case when Gender = 'Female' then 1 else 0 end) as female 
from @Voter
group by ward
```